# I would like to reverse a char array, why it fails when using Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder())?

Tags: java, string, sorting, char, reverse

If I reverse a string array, it works fine when using
`Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder())`
but why it does not work on char Array?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] temp = new String[] {"ab","aa","ac"};
    Arrays.sort(temp, Collections.reverseOrder());
            
    char[] arr = new char[]{'a','b','c'};
    Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of primitives. `char` is a primitive. `Collections.sort()` works on collections of objects.

To solve the problem do like this ...

```
 Character[] arr = new Character[]{'a','b','c'};
 Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Instead of using a primitive type use its wrapper type, which is an object. Then, everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.reverseOrder() won´t work on primitive types in java such as char type.

You will need to sort it and then reverse using for loop or put chars into string etc.